# java PowerMockito ignore method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermockito

In a unit test, how can I ignore a call to a method as shown below?

```
void methodToBeTested(){
     // do some stuff
     methodToBeSkipped(parameter);
     // do more stuff
}

void methodToBeSkipped{
     // do stuff outside of test scope
}

@Test
void TestMethodToBeTested(){
     TestedClass testedClass = new TestedClass();
     testedClass.methodToBeTested();
     // asserts etc.
}
```

Comment: Your request shows a *design problem*! Your class is doing too much. The *stuff out of test scope* should live in a separate class and you should *inject* an instance of that  other class as a dependency to your class under test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need [powermockito](/questions/tagged/powermockito) for this. You could simply [`spy`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) the object you're going to test and mock out the method you want to skip:

```
@Test
public void testMethodToBeTested() {
    TestedClass testedClass = Mockito.spy(new TestedClass());
    Mockito.doNothing().when(testedClass).methodToBeSkipped();

    testedClass.methodToBeTested();
    // Assertions etc.
}
```